# with css3, how to make table row expand/contract slowly?

Tags: javascript, css, transform, transition

would like to gradually "open" and "close" row in a table, with the rows beneath being pushed down or pulled up as appropriate.

am able to get div to expand / contract by using `transition` for timing and `transform` for sizing (unable to use `height`)

#### sample.css

```
h1 { transition all 600s linear; }
h1.sqeeze {  transform scale( 1.0, 0.0 ); }
```

but this has no effect on the surrounding environment.  the `h1.squeeze` effectively goes to a `0px` height, but the blocks following the `h1` remain as they were.

what I'd like is a mechanism where something can be expanded / contracted, like a `tr` or `div` or `li`, and the surrounding blocks respond my making room or by taking the space newly available - like `display: none;` in slow motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8qMS2/4/).(Added the click operation.)

Css code looks like

```
transition:height 2s;
```

You can try it to see whether i understood what you wanted or not.

Comment: when I played with this before, `transition` would not work with `height` but would work with `transform` - if works with `height` then that would certainly be the ticket.  will test further and get back.

Comment: results in `chrome` are as previous: the transition is instantaneous - not taking 2 seconds as the transition says.  what browser is this working in?

Comment: I get that worked at
Chrome 27.0.1453.116 and IE 10.0.9200.

So,Your machine may be the reason.

Comment: just to make sure, on your fiddle, when you hover over `div2` it opens wider, taking a full two seconds to do so - is that right?

Comment: I didn't measure it, but i think yes.It opened in slow motion almost two seconds.

Comment: thanks for checking - evidently a bug on my side.  will work with chrome guys.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To do that u would need way more code because you can't set the size of all childs based on the parent size. Things like text and fixed size will not contract. I would suggest that you fade in/out with alpha instead.

Comment: I do not think I explained very well.  Imagine three `div`s: if you `display:none` then `display:block` the middle `div`, the bottom `div` will move up or down.  Imagine the same, except the bottom `div` moves up or down slowly.